# Click issues in the list view and spannable string in android

Tags: android, listview

I am facing issues in the `TextView` field where it is placed in the list view.

- In the Text-field there are three spanable string where first spanable string is clickable span() and the other two is a static.
- My problem is when i click any area in the list view i am getting the list item was clicked , but i click the other two static text field , list view click is not detected .

**Code:**

**TextField Click:**

```
holder.txtmail = new SpannableString(rowItems.get(position).getTxtEmail());
holder.txtmail.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.color)), 0, holder.txtmail.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
holder.txtmail.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(strText), 0, holder.txtmail.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
holder.mainName.setText(holder.txtmail);
holder.txtSt = new SpannableString(rowItems.get(position).getTxtSt());
holder.txtSt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK),0, holder.txtSt.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
holder.mainName.append(holder.txtSt);
holder.txtEvt = new SpannableString(rowItems.get(position).getTxtEvt());
holder.txtEvt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, holder.txtEvt.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
holder.txtEvt.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, holder.txtEvt.length(), 0);
holder.txtEvt.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(rowItems.get(position).getTxtEvt()), 0, holder.txtmail.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
holder.mainName.append(holder.txtEvt);
holder.mainName.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
holder.mainName.setFocusable(false);
holder.mainName.setClickable(false);  

private class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    String clicked;

    private MyClickableSpan(String string) {
        super();
        this.clicked = string;
    }

    public void onClick(View tv) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "" + clicked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setUnderlineText(false);
    }
}
```

**List view Click:**

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

**XMl for List view Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ltMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ltSub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ltMain"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should add your item layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add MyClickableSpan to the non clickable item too and perform the list item click on it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the clickable property of other two `TextViews` to false.
Since they are clickable by default, when you click on it, it detects the click of `TextView` and not of the list item.